# Plotting a piecewise function in R

Tags: r, plot

I was reading other similar questions in this site about how to plot a piecewise function in R and I write this code

```
myfunction = function(x){(x<-1)*(x^2+2*x)+(-1<=x & x<=1)*x+(x>1)*(-1)}
g=Vectorize(myfunction)
plot(g,-5,5)
```

However the plot is just a straight line, that is, it doesnt plot the defined function. What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<-` is assignment and won't be interpreted as "less than negative". Add a space in there and you'll see what you expect.

```
myfunction = function(x){(x< -1)*(x^2+2*x)+(-1<=x & x<=1)*x+(x>1)*(-1)}
```

Comment: Note that in general it would be better to break this up to multiple lines and add more spaces in to make it more readable but I only did the bare minimum to make your current code work.

Comment: I find following a style guide helps to avoid errors like this (e.g., [tidyverse](http://style.tidyverse.org/index.html) or [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)).